# Parse string which contain special character

Tags: java

How to Parse string which contain special character like

```
I ][][came][][][I][][][][Saw][][][][][][I][][][][Won][][][][
```

Can anyone please solve it

Comment: Could you give a few sample input / output strings?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're after something like this:

```
String str = "I ][][came][][][I][][][][Saw][][][][][][I][][][][Won][][][][";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", " ");  // keep alpha-numeric characters.
System.out.println(str);
```

prints:

```
I came I Saw I Won
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for ascii values of alphabets and space alone.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the [unicode codes](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) of your special characters and use these codes to parse the string:

```
String specialChar = "\u00f1";
String specialString = "En Espa\u00f1ol";
specialString.split(specialChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as the answer above.
But different pattern for regex.

```
String str = "I ][][came][][][I][][][][Saw][][][][][][I][][][][Won][][][][";

//Search for numeric and alpha characters.
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z]+", " ");  

System.out.println(str);
```

+1 for the first answer

cheers!